# Can I make a sprite image from these images using asp.net image using <asp:Image's?

Tags: asp.net, css, sprite, css-sprites

I have a row of 12 flags on an asp.net (vb) website at the top of my home page to allow the user to choose their language.  Various speed tests like YSlow and Google Speed, are telling me to **sprite these images** to **minimize the http requests**.  How would I go about doing so, if they're asp:image's, AND, there's a hover image?

For now, I have 12 linkbuttons; they look like this (note, when you **hover over a flag, that creates the hover image above it**):

[image: When you hover over a flag, the pop-up image appears, as seen here:]

Here is what my code for the images look like:

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelectEnglish" runat="server"
  CommandArgument="en" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"
  class="flagbutton">      
  <asp:Image ID="Image8" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagen.png" height="15" 
  width="26"
  tooltip="View this website in English" title="View this website in English"/>
  <img class="map" src="images/flaghoveren.png" height="40" width="120" alt="View this 
  website in English"/>
  </asp:LinkButton>

  <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSelectGerman" runat="server"
  CommandArgument="de" OnClick="RequestLanguageChange_Click"
  class="flagbutton">      
  <asp:Image ID="Image7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/flagde.png" height="15" 
  width="26"
  tooltip="View this website in Deutsch" title="View this website in Deutsch"/>
  <img class="map" src="images/flaghoverde.png" height="40" width="120" alt="View this
  website in Deutsch"/>
  </asp:LinkButton>
```

And so on ... 12 link buttons.  Is this as simple as just putting a CssClass in the asp:Image tags and if so, how would I do that?  Or is this something more complex?

Each flag is 26 x 15 and there are 12 of them.  Is it possible to create a sprite image of these and **retain the hover effects**?  I'm thinking the sprite image will have to be 334 pixels (24 x 12 + 11 x 2 for the padding in between) wide x (I don't know what the height would be).  Or should I just forget about spriting this and leave it as is?  Thanks for any guidance anybody can offer; I know this might be a tough one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display them via a css sprite sheet, you'll want to get rid of the actual image tags within the link buttons as css sprite sheets are applied via the background-image property.

Since it looks like each  has a class of "flagbutton", you can specify that every element with class flag button has a background image (your sprite sheet). That would look something like this:

```
.flagbutton {
    background-image:url(images/myspritesheet.png);
    width:26px;
    height:15px;
    margin-right:2px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

Then, since each  has a unique ID, you can specify in your css file a unique background position for each link button, which will allow you to basically slide the sprite sheet around within each flag's window to position it to show the correct flag. That would something like this:

```
#btnSelectEnglish {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#btnSelectGerman {
    background-position: 0 -26px;
}
```

This would display the first 26px x 15px portion of the sprite sheet in the english box, and the second 26px x 15px portion of the sprite sheet in the german box.

You won't need to add spacing between the flags in your sprite sheet -- as that will be covered by the margin-right in the .flagbutton definition above. Without rollovers, I think your final sprite sheet will be height 312px (26 x 12) by 15px tall.

If you want to add rollovers into the mix, simply place the rollover version of each image below its counterpart in the sprite sheet. This would double the height of your sprite sheet. Then, add a hover class for each of your IDs to cover hovering like so:

```
#btnSelectEnglish:hover {
    background-position: -15px 0;
}

#btnSelectGerman:hover {
    background-position: -15px -26px;
}
```

This will shift your sprites up to reveal the hover image.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kleezy, for taking the time to read this complicated question and respond with an intricate answer.  I'm almost done trying to implement your solution.  I just had a quick question.  How would my final sprite image, sprite-flags.png, know what image to display when being hovered over?  For instance, if I hover over the English button, how would it know what and where to display flaghoveren?  Again, I really do appreciate the time and effort in helping me out with this!

Comment: No problem. If you set up your single sprite sheet to have two rows of flags, with the original flags on the top and the rollover versions of the flag on the bottom, then by setting the background-position to the same x value but a negative y value on hover, the rollover version will display while they're hovering. Does that make sense? You're basically just sliding the sprite sheet up inside the hovered div. Here's an example that has 4 different button states. Yours would only have 2 rows. http://media.smashingmagazine.com/images/css-sprites/sprites2.gif

Comment: Yes ... currently the hover effect is controlled by this on my stylesheet:  a.flagbutton:hover .map {
display:block;
position:absolute;
top:58%;
right:45px;
margin-top:0;
}

Comment: Gotcha. If you implement the above -- that hover style won't affect anything anymore. You'll remove the hover images that you currently have inside each link button, leaving just the link button itself. It should simplify the overall structure of your code (assuming you can do that).

Comment: Almost there!  The only problem is that all 12 flags are English flags ... but I'm working on it -- you've definitely pointed me in the right direction.  With just a little heuristic trial-and-error, I'll get there.  Thanks again for your time and efforts, Kleezy!

Comment: OK, good luck. Just remember, you change the flags by changing the background position of each flag. The first value of background-position is how many pixels to shift the background image to the left/right and the second is how much to shift the background image up/down.

Comment: I guess I didn't succeed on this one; I just have nothing in my css or master page coding calling the hover images (the white, round cornered picture with the circular flag, like flaghoveren.png, flagoverde.png, flagoverfr.png, etc.) ... I'll keep trying to figure it out though!  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Did you add the hover elements that I mentioned in my answer (the last code block)? If so, perhaps you can edit your question to show your current code and I can see if I can spot the issue.

Comment: Yes .. so for instance, I have #btnSelectGerman:hover {
    background-position: -15px -26px;
}   and then the next language, French, I have #btnSelectGerman:hover {
    background-position: -15px -52px;
} .... etc., for all 12 flags.  I'll still give it a go, though -- gotta get my 2 hours of sleep!